# Maven、Tomcat、java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10961

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

My IDE is Eclipse.
Maven Version: 3.5.0

I want to build my web project by maven, following errors are printed out when I build my project.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) > package @ LEVEMCS >>>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.571 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-29T17:10:58+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 10961
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10961
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2502)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:1604)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1434)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1131)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:3856)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:595)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor.read(DefaultModelProcessor.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1097)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:829)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:331)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:321)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:325)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:353)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
```

when it happened, I thought there are some error in my pom.xml.

My pom.xml is:

```
<build>
    <finalName>LEVEMCS</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <server>tomcat7</server>
          <port>8081</port>
          <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-alpha2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I have tried it again and again, but can't find what mistake I make.

The setting in maven have not problem, because I build an another javaFX project sucessfully.

Comment: It would appear you have a broken XML processing instruction 
somewhere, the kind that looks like this; 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: Your mean is there are may some faults in my xml of spring and springmvc? @TheHound.developer

Comment: No..No..You can check that your pom.xml contains this,:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is certainly a local problem. So first check the validity of your maven config files:

.m2/settings.xml

M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml

If these look fine, then the problem may also be caused by a "corrupt" (bad XML) pom.xml.The easiest way is to just wipe your ~/.m2/repository, to let Maven re-download everything.

Comment: Yeah~~~I wipe my repository and re-download,it works!

Comment: Happy to help. Please upvote if you felt it as useful @GloryChou